# htaacces redirect

Tags: .htaccess

How to :

domain.com.ua/e107_plugins/forum/forum_viewtopic.php?847 **redirect** to domain.com.ua/blog.php?blog=1847

- 847 + 1000- it's new ID valud.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you could rephrase this with complete, clear sentences, then you can get a better answer.  What have you tried so far?  Are you using Apache?  What version?  Do you have mod_rewrite available?  Can you give more than one example of desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) with `awk '{ print $0 + 1000 ; fflush() }'`.